# Adding a child view controller and changing its label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I got a view controller named IntroViewController in my storyboard and I want to add this as a child to another view controller like this:

```
     IntroViewController *introViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View1"];
     [introViewController.textLabel setText:@"test"];
     [self addChildViewController:introViewController];
```

On the IntroViewController I've put a label named textLabel on it in the storyboard, if I run the program it works and shows me the view controller, but the text doesn't get changed. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instantiate a view controller from a storyboard, the view is not loaded until it is actually presented on screen.  At the point in your code you have posted `introViewController.textLabel` is nil.

One option you could do is add a property to your `IntroViewController` class and instead set that:

```
introViewController.initialText = @"test";
```

Then, inside `-viewDidLoad` of your `IntroViewController` the label will be instantiated so you can make the call:

```
[self.textLabel setText:self.initialText];
```

It is also worth noting that most of the time it would be recommended to have a view controller be the one to set values on the views it owns, rather than some other view controller.

Comment: All right, this works, however you need to remove the square brackets here: introViewController.initialText = @"test"; and maybe its better if I just make a function in IntroViewController and set the label there, and then in the other view controller call that function and pass a variable with it?